# How to duplicate a row based on column or cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to duplicate rows in excel using VBA and merge columns into one.

The VBA code below hide some columns. i need help edit my code to show all columns(copy col A through col Q).

This is how the original data looks like
[image]

This is how i would like to end up to
[image]

This is how i get using the code listed below (**problem**: doesnt show or copy col. B to Col P)

[image]

I would like to show all columns between A and Q. the code below hides all columns except the first and merged one(Col A and merged col on col. B).

```
 Sub SortMacro()
  Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
  Dim OutSheet As Worksheet

  Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
  Set OutSheet = Sheets.Add

 With SourceSheet
   Out_i = 1
    For r = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 17 To 20 'or For each i in Array(17,18,20)
        OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, 1) = .Cells(r, 1)
        OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, 2) = .Cells(r, i)
        Out_i = Out_i + 1
    Next
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I what to show all the columns, the above code hides all the columns between the first and the merged one which col. Q i want to show all columns in addition to the merged cell

Comment: This question obviously shows effort, but like @JohnSaunders I am confused as to what you are asking. Can you clarify at all?

Comment: Do you want to copy columns A:P to a new sheet and then merge the values from columns Q:T on the old sheet into column Q on the new sheet?

Comment: What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: @rmayer06 thanks!, The VBA above doesn't show or  copy col B to col P. i would like to edit my code to show all columns(copy col A throught col Q)

Comment: @barrowc correct that is what im trying to accomplish, thanks!

Comment: OK, so please clarify your question by adding to it. Also, it is not clear what is happening to columns past Q.

Comment: @rmayer06 sorry for the confusion, thanks!

Comment: Now that your question is edited, I suggest changing your title to better explain what you need, which will probably get you more views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my interpretation of what you need. I've added a loop to copy columns A:P into each new row

```
Sub SortMacro()

Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim OutSheet As Worksheet

Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
Set OutSheet = Sheets.Add

With SourceSheet
  Out_i = 1
  For r = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Create a new row for each column entry in Q:T
    For i = 17 To 20
      ' Check the cell isn't empty before creating a new row
      If (.Cells(r, i).Value <> "") Then
        ' Copy columns A:P
        For j = 1 To 16
          OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, j) = .Cells(r, j)
        Next j

        ' Copy the current column from Q:T
        OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, 17) = .Cells(r, i)
        Out_i = Out_i + 1
      End If
    Next i
  Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you @barrowc: what if i want to copy the merged cell from Q:T to col N instead of placing at the end? Also how can i skip when blank cell exist? Thanks!!

Comment: What should happen to what is already in column N at that point?

Comment: the reason is i want to have one columns next col S and eliminated when runs the macro. But is there anyways to **skip when blank cell exist for example on the above 1st picture let say `S2` is empty** which is `ItemID=600204` so `600204` row has two be appear/copy only twice while others three times. thank you!!

Comment: I've adjusted the code to skip blank cells in columns Q:T